# Is there any api gateway framework for websocket

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, api-gateway

Usually we would have a api gateway for rest service, now I have a webscoket micro service, is there any way to use this api gateway for websocket? Thanks BTW, I am using spring boot

Comment: From my experience with web socket and micro-services. Gateway isn't really needed. Even if you somehow add it, it will be a huge pain. What you can do instead is to have a separate micro-service a.k.a websocket-service that listens to Kafka topic and then convertAndSend. All other services should use Kafka Producer to queue up the message. This is what I have implemented in my project with 16 micro-services producing different type of events, and 1 websocket-service that sends these events to clients.

Comment: Regarding gateway, if there's no gateway, where do you do authentication and authorization? Regarding kafka, is it too heavy to use kafka for websocket?

Comment: Kafka is a queueing system, not mandatory. It's not too heave on resources, but it depends on your use case. I have used for real-time trading application, where messages are triggered in heavy volumes per second. 
For Authorization and authentication, you can configure ChannelInterceptor in Websocket-service itself that does it.